# C++ letters to nato phonetic throwing out random letters

Tags: c++, vector

Parden the kinda hacky code, but whenever I compile this it runs fine until it comes aross the letter 'u' then it spits out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3qGZ.png),I'm sure it's something glaringly simple i'm overlooking but can't for the life of me see it.What am I doing wrong?

```
/*
 * Converts letter into nato phonetic equivilant
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> alphabet(26);

    alphabet[97] = "ALPHA"; //0
    alphabet[98] = "BRAVO";
    alphabet[99] = "CHARLIE";
    alphabet[100] = "DELTA";
    alphabet[101] = "ECHO";
    alphabet[102] = "FOXTROT";
    alphabet[103] = "GOLF";
    alphabet[104] = "HOTEL";
    alphabet[105] = "INDIA";
    alphabet[106] = "JULIET";
    alphabet[107] = "KILO";
    alphabet[108] = "LIMA";
    alphabet[109] = "MIKE";
    alphabet[110] = "NOVEMBER";
    alphabet[111] = "OSCAR";
    alphabet[112] = "PAPA";
    alphabet[113] = "QUEBEC";
    alphabet[114] = "ROMEO";
    alphabet[115] = "SIERRA";
    alphabet[116] = "TANGO";
    alphabet[117] = "UNIFORM";
    alphabet[118] = "VICTOR";
    alphabet[119] = "WHISKEY";
    alphabet[120] = "X-RAY";
    alphabet[121] = "YANKEE";
    alphabet[122] = "ZULU";

    std::cout << "Enter a word:" << std::endl;
    std::string word;
    getline(std::cin, word);
    std::system("clear");

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        int num;
        num = word.at(i);
        std::cout << alphabet[num] << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that it has undefined behavior. Your vector is 26-element long, but you set elements starting at index 97.

To fix this problem, make your vector 123-element long, or use `num-97` for indexes, both in set up and printing.

```
std::vector<std::string> alphabet = {
    "ALPHA"
,   "BRAVO"
,   "CHARLIE"
,   "DELTA"
,   "ECHO"
,   "FOXTROT"
,   "GOLF"
,   "HOTEL"
,   "INDIA"
,   "JULIET"
,   "KILO"
,   "LIMA"
,   "MIKE"
,   "NOVEMBER"
,   "OSCAR"
,   "PAPA"
,   "QUEBEC"
,   "ROMEO"
,   "SIERRA"
,   "TANGO"
,   "UNIFORM"
,   "VICTOR"
,   "WHISKEY"
,   "X-RAY"
,   "YANKEE"
,   "ZULU"
};
...
std::cout << alphabet[num-'a'] << std::endl;
```

**Note:** Readability of your code would improve if you start using character literals in place of integer constants, i.e. `alphabet['u'] = "UNIFORM";` instead of `alphabet[117] = "UNIFORM";`. The end result is the same, but the readers wouldn't have to perform lookups in the UNICODE table to see the meaning of code point 117.

Comment: I feel silly now.I had an inkling starting the vector at 97 would be the issue,thanks for the helpful answer it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is broken from the start, because you are writing to vector positions that do not exist!

Once you've started doing that, basically anything can happen, including the code appearing to work, or getting strange values, or spontaneously transporting the Mother of Dragons herself from her alternate reality into *this* reality and into my neighbourhood (yes, please!).

Your vector has 26 elements in it. The indices of those elements go from 0 to 25, not from 97 to 122.

You can apply some primary school arithmetic (i.e. subtracting then later re-adding 97) to offset the indices for storage, or you can use a `std::map<int, std::string>` instead (which would be my recommendation).

Comment: @Quentin: Gah! I've lost some characters! Wonder what they were :( My automated SO-answer-writing program clearly has some UB in it somewhere. Oh, Khaleesi? Wherefore art though Khaleesi?

Comment: Oh my, I would've never guessed !

Comment: @Quentin: And this seems to have lost me the rep-race, against newer answers. :(

Answer (score 2):

You use vector like a map, by indexing it at places where no elements exists, maybe you want a map? If so then :

```
  #include <map>

   int main()
   {
      std::map<int, std::string> alphabet;
```

and it should work fine